# Overriding/exteding model

Tags: laravel

I use the Package "laravel/cashier-mollie" which is installed via composer into the vendor dir and has an model: \Laravel\Cashier\Order\OrderNumberGenerator

I want to override this model to implement my own ordernumber logic.

I created a new model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Payments;

use Laravel\Cashier\Order\Order;
use Laravel\Cashier\Order\OrderNumberGenerator;

class OwnOrderNumberGenerator extends OrderNumberGenerator
{


    protected $offset;
    /**
     * OrderNumberGenerator constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->offset = config('cashier.order_number_generator.offset');
    }
    /**
     * Generate an order reference.
     *
     * @return string
     */

    public function generate()
    {
        $number = str_pad(
            $this->offset + Order::count() + 1,
            4,
            '0',
            STR_PAD_LEFT
        );
        $numbers = str_split($number, 4);
        return now()->month .'-'. now()->year . ' '. implode('-',[
            now()->year,
            $numbers[0],
            $numbers[1],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Maybe I do something wrong but it won't work.. What do I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean it wont work ??? do you get an error ??

Comment: how do you use this new class? I mean, how does your code know to call this and not the original?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the constructor from your model extension, and use trait instead. With a function inside the trait called `public function initializeYourTraitName() { $this->offset = config('cashier.order_number_generator.offset'); }`